Where and when is RDR bass guitar made?
I acquired a bass guitar that has a BRAND name RDR, and I don't know how much could be the value of this when I am going to sell it.
Can you help me with where and when RDR bass guitar is made?

I suggest taking it to a professional. We absolutely would not be able to appraise it over the internet. We might be able to tell something about the history of the brand, but a quick googling yields no results except for things about catching largemouth bass in the video game Red Dead Redemption. Many brands are quickly "invented" to slap onto generic instruments.

AFAIK, price appraisal is off-topic here, so I tried to clarify the title and the question body by focusing on the other mentioned question about the history/origin.
